# Working with Delicious API json response

Tags: php, arrays

When I try to find out the total count of delicious bookmarks, Delicious returns a json file which when decoded is:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => stdClass Object ( 
        [hash] => e60558db2d649c8a1933d50f9e5b199a 
        [title] => ISRAEL: Thousands march in Jerusalem rally, Israel still kicking 
                       new families out of land they've owned for 60+ years 
        [url] => http://english.aljazeera.net/news/middleeast/2010/03/2010362141312196.html
        [total_posts] => 2 
        [top_tags] => Array () 
     )
)
```

The array is a stdClass Object. How can I extract [total_count] using PHP.

P.S Since I could not figure out how to extract it, I am using strpos to find 'total_count' and then I am cutting the string from that position and then extracting integers out of it. :)
BUt it is way too long.

## Solved

Comment: Do you mean totat_posts or the total number of elements in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a second argument, `true`, in your `json_decode`, it will return a regular array as opposed to an object. You might find this easier to work with.

`$array = json_decode($json, true);`

Answer (score 4):

If you pass a second argument, true, in your json_decode, it will return a regular array as opposed to an object. You might find this easier to work with.

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
echo $stdClass->total_posts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean [total_posts]? If so, you should use `$delArray[0]->total_posts`.

See http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php for samples on accessing object properties.